# Why does time need to be a macro?

Tags: time, clojure, macros

The [Clojure source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.10.1/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L3884) gives the following definition of `time`

```
(defmacro time
  "Evaluates expr and prints the time it took.  Returns the value of
 expr."
  {:added "1.0"}
  [expr]
  `(let [start# (. System (nanoTime))
         ret# ~expr]
     (prn (str "Elapsed time: " (/ (double (- (. System (nanoTime)) start#)) 1000000.0) " msecs"))
     ret#))
```

Why does this need to be a macro? What about it could not be done with a function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because function evaluates its arguments before it starts working with them. You can write `time` as function and try to call it:

```
(defn my-time [expr]
  (let [start (System/nanoTime)
        ret expr]
    (prn (str "Elapsed time: " (/ (double (- (System/nanoTime) start)) 1000000.0) " msecs"))
    ret))

(my-time (Thread/sleep 1000))
"Elapsed time: 0.005199 msecs"
=> nil
```

Compare that with `time` macro:

```
(time (Thread/sleep 1000))
"Elapsed time: 1000.1222 msecs"
=> nil
```

Function `my-time` evaluated argument `(Thread/sleep 1000)`, symbol `expr` got value `nil` and then body of that function happened- two `(System/nanoTime)` were called shortly after each other, because value of `expr` was already computed.

Macro `time` didn't evaluate `(Thread/sleep 1000)`, but expanded to:

```
(macroexpand `(time (Thread/sleep 1000)))
=>
(let*
 [start__6136__auto__ (. java.lang.System (clojure.core/nanoTime)) ret__6137__auto__ (java.lang.Thread/sleep 1000)]
 (clojure.core/prn
  (clojure.core/str
   "Elapsed time: "
   (clojure.core//
    (clojure.core/double (clojure.core/- (. java.lang.System (clojure.core/nanoTime)) start__6136__auto__))
    1000000.0)
   " msecs"))
 ret__6137__auto__)
```

and functions were called in this order: `(System/nanoTime)`, `(Thread/sleep 1000)` and other `(System/nanoTime)`, which returns correct time.